# How Share Variables Among View and Sub Views in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I have a date picker, when the date selection value changes, I would like to store it in a string array called filterSelections, how do I do that? Thanks in advance.

```
import SwiftUI
public var filterSelections: [String: Any]?

func setFilterSelections(name: String, selectedValue: Any) {
    filterSelections[name] = selectedValue
}


struct myMainSwiftUIView: View{

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack{
                mySub1View()
            }
        }
    }
}


struct mySub1View: View {
@State public var fromDate: Date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: DateComponents(year: -40), to: Date()) ?? Date()

    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing:10) {
            VStack(alignment:.leading, spacing:20) {
            DatePicker(selection: $fromDate, displayedComponents: .date) {
                Text("From")
                    .font(.body)
                    .fixedSize()
            }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    

}
```

Comment: Your question isn't really clear to me. How does the `Date` relate to the `String`?

Comment: The date picker value would be part of the filter selection. Like this ["fromDate":  2020/01/31  ] My bad, it is not string, it is Any. I corrected it.

Comment: Why is the filter a *Dictionary* of type `[String:Any]` -- are there going to be multiple entries?

Comment: Yes, there are other entries beside the date picker.

Comment: Do you think Environment variable would be a good candidate for this situation?

Comment: Could be, but there's honestly not really enough code here for me to figure out what's actually supposed to be going on. But, in general, if you're sharing state between views, you'll use an ObservableObject (either by passing it directly or via an environment object). The [String:Any] still has me concerned -- why is it `Any` -- do you not know what is getting filtered? Also using `!` to force unwrap is almost always a bad idea, as it'll crash your program if the variable is nil. Types in Swift are generally capitalized.

Comment: @Michelle: If you have issue with **.onChange or iOS 14.0** then use **didSet** on **selection** for same work, should I gave you example code?

Comment: @swifPunk, that would great! Put in as a different, I will mark it as answer. Thank you so much for your help and your time!

Answer (score 1):

It is so simple, make an array and store all of them, do not make more complex in your code, if you want export your Date array then use **StateObject**, there is really not a big issue. after all then start working on your stored array, for example where and how you want use it!

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        
        mySub1View()

    }
}
```

---

```
struct mySub1View: View {

    @State private var selection: Date = Date()
    @State private var selectionArray: [Date] = [Date]()
    
    var body: some View {

 if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
        DatePicker(selection.description, selection: $selection, displayedComponents: .date)
            .onChange(of: selection) { newValue in
                
                selectionArray.append(newValue)
                print(selectionArray)
            }
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's hard for me to see the application of what storing *all* of the changes to the date picker would be, since there wouldn't be any way to cancel them out (and, in pre-iOS 14, I think the wheel would make this a particular crazy looking list when things were changing).

My suspicion is that you probably want the date along with some other filters added together. And, you specified wanting to share that state between views and subviews, which I've tried to accommodate. I also used the date format that you asked for.

I did not include the `[String:Any]` as your question said "array", not dictionary.

Lots of guess work here, since it's not totally clear what your goal is, but hopefully this gives you some ideas of how to share state.

```
class FilterViewModel : ObservableObject {
    @Published var dateFilter : Date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: DateComponents(year: -40), to: Date()) ?? Date()
    @Published var myOtherFilter = "Filter1"
    
    static var formatter = DateFormatter()
    
    var allFilters : [String] {
        Self.formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd"
        return [myOtherFilter, Self.formatter.string(from: dateFilter)]
    }
}

struct ContentView: View{
    @StateObject private var filterModel = FilterViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack{
                MySub1View(filterModel: filterModel)
            }
            ForEach(filterModel.allFilters, id: \.self) { filter in
                Text(filter)
            }
        }
    }
}


struct MySub1View: View {
    @ObservedObject var filterModel : FilterViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing:10) {
            VStack(alignment:.leading, spacing:20) {
                DatePicker(selection: $filterModel.dateFilter, displayedComponents: .date) {
                    Text("From")
                        .font(.body)
                        .fixedSize()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```